# Substring ranges (Java)

Tags: java, string, substring

How could I obtain three substrings from one that it something like "I am 50"? I have to reverse it ( "50 am I" ) but only need to know how the ranges are (not valid ranges like "from 3 to 5" or similars because the words may vary). Thank you.

```
ss1 = string.substring(0, index); // index = " ";
ss2 = string.substring(index+1, **?** );
ss3 = string.substring( **?** , string.length());
```

Comment: `ss1 = string.substring(0, index); // index = " ";` - surely this is wrong; index can't be a String?

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps to follow:

- split the original string on the basis of one or more spaces
- iterate each words in reverse order

Sample code:

```
    String str = "I am 50";
    String[] array = str.split("\\s+");

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        buffer.append(" ").append(array[i]);
    }
    String reverse = buffer.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.split(" "), which returns you an array of strings - individual words. Then you can reverse the array and calculate the ranges

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `String#split(String)` function here.

What you can do is call `string.split(" ");` and that will split the string into independent words. You can then, just reverse the array.

---

```
String str = "I am 50";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str.length);
String[] words = str.split(" ");
for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    builder.append(words[i]);
    builder.append(' ');
}
String result = builder.toString().trim();
```

Comment: Change the condition to > 0, append the last word after the loop, and then there's no need for the trim.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to using the Apache Commons `ArrayUtils` and `StringUtils` classes, then this is the shortest way

```
String[] words = string.split("\\s");
ArrayUtils.reverse(words);
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(words," "));
```